# UI Route resolve not working on page reload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, resolve

I have an app with view routing using UI Route.

On `/berlinerliste/` it triggers a function and displays an array of objects.

On click to one of those objects the view changes to `/berlinerliste/{id}/`, and displays details of the particular object.

The problem is on page reload on one of these individual objects with `/berlinerliste/{id}/` URL, which results in an page without data.

Here's how my service looks like:

```
.factory('SearchService', ['$http', function($http) {

  var service = {

    flatexhibitors : [],
    datafairs : [],
    flatexhibitorsuni : [],
    datafairsuni : [],

    getAllExhibitors : function () { //first call to get all items on page load
        var searchindex = 'XX';
        var url = '../getexhibitors.php';
        var config = {
            params: {
                search: searchindex
            },
            cache:true
        };
        $http.get(url, config).then(function (data) {
          service.datafairs = data.data.rows;
          for (var i in service.datafairs) {
            service.flatexhibitors.push(service.datafairs[i].doc);
          };
          return service.flatexhibitors;
        });
    },

    getAllPeople: function() { // call to reload data and the filter it 
      var searchindex = 'XX';
      var url = '../getexhibitors.php';
      var config = {
          params: {
              search: searchindex
          },
          cache:true
      };
      return $http.get(url, config).then(function (resp) {
        service.datafairsuni = resp.data.rows;
        for (var i in service.datafairs) {
          service.flatexhibitorsuni.push(service.datafairs[i].doc);
        };
        return service.flatexhibitorsuni;
        console.log(service.flatexhibitorsuni);
      });
    },

    findExh : function(id){
      function personMatchesParam(exhibitor) {
        return exhibitor.slug === id;
        console.log(exhibitor.slug);
      }
      return service.getAllPeople().then(function (data) {
        return data.find(personMatchesParam)
      });

    }
  }

  service.getAllExhibitors();

  return service;

}])
```

And here's how my view configuration looks like:

```
.config(function($stateProvider) {

  var berlinerState = {
    name: 'berliner',
    url: '/berlinerliste/',
    views: {
      'header': {   
        templateUrl: 'header.htm'   
      },
      'main':{    
        templateUrl: 'bl2017.htm'    
      }
    }
  }

  var exhibitorState = { 
    name: 'exhibitor', 
    url: '/berlinerliste/{id}', 
    views: {
      'header': {   
        templateUrl: 'header.htm'  
      },
      'main':{    
        templateUrl: 'exhibitor.htm'    
      }
    },
    resolve: {
      exhibitor: function(SearchService, $stateParams) {
        return SearchService.findExh($stateParams.id);
      }
    }
  }

  $stateProvider.state(berlinerState);
  $stateProvider.state(exhibitorState);
})
```

Aside from the fact that the `/berlinerliste/{id}/` reload won't work, it slows the thing down, as on every click on an object, I'm:

- Making a http call (redundant if it's not page reload, as I did it before on page load)
- Filtering the item by id
- Displaying the result correctly if it comes from `/berlinerliste/`, not displaying anything on page reload.

Any tips on how to fix this?

I think that ideally the redundant http call (and the whole resolve) should be made only on page reload, and not when coming from the parent URL.

What am I missing?

You can see it live [here](http://cccctanger.com/discovery/exhibitors/#!/berlinerliste/)

### UPDATE

See [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/2SSO4Y?p=preview) example from the UI Router guys where they do exactly what I'm trying to. For them it works, for me it doesn't.

Comment: Why don't u use $stateParams https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/url-routing ?

Comment: @Vivz I edited it in the code with $stateParams, same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Reloading the page is equivalent to re-initiating your application. Since it is a single page application, it simply would result in loosing all data because now factories, services, controllers, etc would be re-loaded. You would either have fetch that data again from the server or maintain it in browser's local storage. I would suggest you to grab the id from the url, and shift your api call from parent route to the child route i.e. `#!/berlinerliste/{id}`.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to do! See edit for Plunkr from the UI Router guys where they do exactly that. For them it works, for me it doesnt.

Comment: I tried your code on chrome and firefox and it is working fine. Do you still have this issue?